# using fdt to compile flex project using flex sdk as runtime shared swc

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, swc, fdt

I've been trying to compile flex project using flex SDK 4.5.1.

I use eclipse FDT.

I want my flex application not to take a lot of space.

my all page contains like 4 different swf files and each one of them contains the entire flex sdk. i'm trying to shrink them up by taking the flex sdk out of them and uploading it to their location.

When I click on properties of my project and I go to `Build Path` and then to `Build Order`,  I made sure that all the relevant swc files are at the top and that are marked `Use as Runtime Shared Code`. of course I'm talking about the flex sdk swc files (spark.swc,mx.swc and so on...)

I also copied and uploaded all these swc files to that same location that my main swf file is located.

when I execute the main swf file. I execute it on firefox browser with firebug opened,
I get many VerifyError exceptions that it can't find Application, UIMovieClip  and others.

I think that the main swf file is not trying to locate the sdk at all and that's why the classes are missing.

any ideas how to resolve the issue?

i pasted the full stack trace below, fdt build path and compiler pages.

[image: fdt build path]

[image: fdt compiler]

```
 VerifyError: Error #1014: Class spark.components::Application could not be found.
 VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.flash::UIMovieClip could not be found.
 Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class spark.components::Application could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.flash::UIMovieClip could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.core::SpriteAsset could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.resources::ResourceBundle could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.resources::ResourceBundle could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.resources::ResourceBundle could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.resources::ResourceBundle could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.resources::ResourceBundle could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.resources::ResourceBundle could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.resources::ResourceBundle could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data.
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.resources::ResourceBundle could not be found.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _class_embed_css_Assets_swf__553552754_mx_skins_cursor_BusyCursor_617494571 is not defined.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable buy_coins_component is not defined.

at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I also copied and uploaded all these `swc` files to that same location
>   that my main swf file is located

`swc` files can't be used at runtime.

Your swf can get flex rsls either from adobe site(or...maybe Apache site) or from other places if you specify rsl urls during compilation.

Those rsls shall be either in `.swf` form or `.swz` form(signed ones).

You can found `.swf` rsls in sdk folders, or you can extract them from `.swc` if you want, however, when your swf is build rsls shall be placed in output folder by compiler(at least they are always populated in `bin-debug` and `bin-release` when building with `Flash Builder`, don't know if `FDT` is different).

You can also use `Charles` to see what urls are being requested by your swf, including rsl urls.

You may also want to avoid using default rsl ursl that are pointing to adobe/apache because they are not always reliable(at least I met problems with them, we had to store all flex rsls on our server).

Comment: thanks for the info. unfortunately fdt didn't provide these files in bin directory. still didn't find a proper solution. your information have been really helpful to understand things. thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with `ant`? If yes, you may find this helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948403/adding-runtime-library-path-to-flex-build-configuration-using-ant-mxmlc-task